# How to get equally spaced audio chunks from .wav file using ffmpeg?

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg

I have a .wav file which I am trying to slice into chunks of .wav files that are each 5 seconds long. I am calling ffmpeg as a sub process from within my Python script.

So far, I tried using this:

```
"/user/local/bin/ffmpeg -i dirconf.UPLOAD/movie.wav -ss " + str(start) + " " + str(end) + " -async 1 " + frame count + ".wav"
```

This ends up giving me repetitive chunks of audio. Is there some way I can get frame_1.wav which has a duration from 0-5s, frame_2.wav which has a duration from 6-10s and so on?

Comment: Is that the complete code, because if yes i would try to put it in a loop that itarate in 5 sec increments over the wav file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the segment muxer.

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -f segment -segment_time 5 -c copy frame-%d.wav
```